# Not able to import dependencies even after doing maven update in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

In my AWS lambda java project, I included the following snippet in my pom.xml.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/bom -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
     <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
     <version>2.13.39</version>
     <type>pom</type>
 </dependency>
```

After I execute maven update on the project and try to import `software.amazon.awssdk.*` it shows an error message saying it can't find any such package.

Is it because the packages are not installed properly by maven?

Answer (score 0):

The bom should go in a dependancy management 
->

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.39</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

A BOM is a list of versions for dependencies. It goes into `<dependencyManagement>`.

This means that a BOM does not add any dependencies to the project. DependencyManagement only fixes versions for dependencies that appear otherwise.

So you need to declare all relevant dependencies in your  `<dependencies>` section.